# In ASP.net MVC Can I process through my cshtml logic before finishing the controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller who has database logic occurring in the controller action. In addition, I know it's probably not ideal but I have some logic occurring my views. This does some sql queries and potentially those queries might update records. I have a transaction that I open at the beginning of my controller's action. In an attempt at dealing w/ this problem, I held it until after the View() call of my action with the hope that the view logic would execute before I had to commit my transaction. However, this doesn't seem to work as it only seems to process the view logic after the controller's action fully completes.

```
ViewBag.Message = message;
                ViewBag.Test = test;

                var result = View();

                LegacyDataManager.Commit();
                Data.Commit();

                return result;
            }
            finally
            {
                LegacyDataManager.Stop();
                Data.CloseInstance();
            }
```

An alternative solution is that I hold off performing the closing of my transactions until the end of the view's logic but this seems even more wrong than what I'm currently trying.

My end goal is that all necessary logic occurs before I close the transaction.

Thanks.

Comment: Execution has left the controller by the time the view is being constructed.

Comment: "it's probably not ideal" - Having database logic in your view is one of the biggest design flaws you can have in an MVC app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In ASP.net MVC Can I process through my cshtml logic before finishing the controller action?

No.

The control flow is that the controller performs its logic and then passes control to the view when it's done and ready to render the view.

It sounds like the root of the problem is that you have too much logic in your view.  For example:

> This does some sql queries and potentially those queries might update records.

That should *definitely not happen* in a view.  A view just renders the result, nothing more.  The only logic therein would be conditionally rendering the view differently based on the state of the model.  It should *not* have side-effects outside of rendering the view.

The current design is fundamentally flawed, your best bet is to correct the design of your application instead of trying to coerce the framework to fit your design.

Comment: I get this and agree. But I have a question: After I move all my logic to the controller there's still the potential for errors to occur. Maybe I have an index off by 1 in a for loop while constructing the view. How do I rollback at that point? In my mind I'd like to rollback because the user will probably press refresh and I don't want the logic to execute again. But I also want the view to render. Does my concern make sense or is there an alternative solution I'm missing that you might be aware of?

Comment: @misterbee180: By the time you're rendering the view there's nothing to "roll back".  The operation has already been performed and the result has been returned.  The view merely presents that result to the user.  An error may occur while presenting the result (such as an incorrect assumption about records being returned, leading to the use of an invalid index or a null reference exception), but the operation performed in the controller was already successfully performed.

Comment: So if this is the case do I need to now write logic to check that the particular step hasn't already occurred and if so don't do things when they inevitably press refresh? This seems like a possible safety measure but I'm ideally not wanting to have to do this if it is also a wrong approach.

Comment: @misterbee180: It's not really clear what you're asking there.  It sounds like you're over-thinking things, and may have even more heavily relied on logic inside your view than indicated in the question.  A controller action performs an operation, a view displays the result.  It's that simple.  Perhaps you can give an example of something which isn't fitting that mold?

Comment: So again, my controller is updating lots of things. Currently the idea is if you come to this page perform the logic and display the results. So what I'm concerned about is an error happening during the view, the user presses refresh, and now the controller logic starts back up again and starts building things, updating things, etc. Unless I totally re-write how the database stores things there's currently no way to know that the works already been performed.

Comment: @misterbee180: That would depend heavily on (1) how you handle errors in the view and present them to the user and (2) how you validate whether a user can/should perform an action.  These concerns are unrelated to whether or not you perform database logic in a view as in the original question, and it sounds like you were relying on incorrect logic in a variety of ways.  If a user shouldn't be able to perform an operation (because it's already been performed, or for any other reason) then the logic which determines that should be in the controller anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199973/discussion-between-misterbee180-and-david).